# Change the collation of a sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, collation

I currently have a view I have created in SQL, It looks at another database, and the view is then used in another process. The problem is that the 2 different databases have a collation conflict, one is CI_AS and the other CP1_CI_AS.

I've looked over the web and seem to find solutions to change the collation on the joins when I link the view to another database, but I can't do that as its an internal process within the product, all it allows me to do is give it a view.

Is there a way I can change the views collation?

Comment: Sorry should have said its in MS SQL server so T-SQL

Comment: Databases, tables, views don't really have collation. A database has a default collation which applies only to string columns that are created without a collation specification. You have two options - permanently change the collation of columns of the source database that your view references or temporarily do that in the view using the collate clause. See documentation for [collate clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15). Given the term "within the product" you might need to ask support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply the COLLATE operator to each column in the SELECT clause.

As an exemple...

With the view :

```
CREATE VIEW V_CUST
AS
SELECT CustID, CustName, CustCity, CustDate
FROM   Customer
GO
```

You need to re-create the view as :

```
CREATE VIEW V_CUST
AS
SELECT CustID, CustName COLLATE French_BIN, CustCity  COLLATE French_BIN, CustDate
FROM   Customer
GO
```

Comment: Thats worked thanks, took me a couple tries as you can't collate ints